# save and retrieve custom plugin options input

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to creating wordpress plugin. I want to create a plugin that display custom page option under setting options of wp-admin section and to save the value of input data and retrieve it, I have gone through the tutorial of [otto press](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/)

I created a folder in `wp-content/plugin/` named `new-setting-plugin` inside the folder is a file named `new-setting-plugin.php` so the entire file path is `wp-content/plugin/new-setting-plugin/new-setting-plugin.php`

the code of the file new-setting-plugin.php is given at the end of the table. After creating the code I went onto plugin page of wp-admin and installed the plugin, it was all fine.

Now when i press "Save setting" button it shows the message "Setting saved" but i can't see the value inside the input fields

I'm attaching my images to preview what it is appearing in my plugin page

When go to the plugin page i see the following input fields:
[image: New Setting Page]

Now I'm entering the value to input fields:
[image: Entering the fields]

When I clicked the "Save Setting" button i got the following message after page refreshed
[image: Page after submit action]

Here is my code

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_page');

if ( !function_exists( 'add_page' ) ) {

    //function to add page under setting options in wordpress admin section
    function add_page() {
        add_options_page('New Setting Page', 'New Setting', 'manage_options', 'plugin', 'plugin_options_frontpage');

    }

}

function plugin_options_frontpage() {

?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon('users'); ?><h2>New Setting Page title</h2>

<form action="options.php" method="post">

<?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections('plugin'); ?>
<table class="form-table"> 

  <tr valign="top">

    <td colspan="2">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>

<?php

}


add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init');
function plugin_admin_init(){
register_setting( 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options_validate' );
add_settings_section('plugin_main', 'Main Settings', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
add_settings_field('plugin_text_input1', 'Input 1', 'plugin_input1', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');
add_settings_field('plugin_text_input2', 'Input 2', 'plugin_input2', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');
}

function plugin_section_text() {
echo '<p>New input setting to be saved.</p>';
}

function plugin_input1() {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
echo "<input id='plugin_input1' class='normal-text code' name='plugin_options[text_string]' size='30' type='text' value='{$options['text_string']}' />";
}


function plugin_input2() {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
echo "<input id='plugin_input2' class='normal-text code' name='plugin_options[text_string]' size='30' type='text' value='{$options['text_string']}' />";
}


function plugin_options_validate($input) {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
$options['text_string'] = trim($input['text_string']);
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i', $options['text_string'])) {
$options['text_string'] = '';
}
return $options;
}

?>
```

What wrong in my code, How can I correct my code and is there a way to show the value of input fields outside the field in same page in a table?

Answer (score 4):

You won't see them there. You have to [`get_options`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

For your code, if you do `var_export( get_option('plugin_options') );` you'll see those saved settings/values.

Answer (score 0):

check the validation criteria.

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i', $options['text_string'])
```

Comment the code inside validation function and test.

```
function plugin_options_validate($input) {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
//$options['text_string'] = trim($input['text_string']);
//if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i', $options['text_string'])) {
//$options['text_string'] = '';
//}
return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the 'name' of the inputs :

```
function manage_lists_cc_input1() {
    $options = get_option('manage_lists_cc_options');
    echo "<input id='manage_lists_cc_input1' class='normal-text code' name='manage_lists_cc_options[0]' size='30' type='text' value='{$options['text_string_0']}' />";
}

function manage_lists_cc_input2() {
    $options = get_option('manage_lists_cc_options');
    echo "<input id='manage_lists_cc_input2' class='normal-text code' name='manage_lists_cc_options[1]' size='30' type='text' value='{$options['text_string_1']}' />";
```

And just change the validate script to get the values (this is a simple example without validation ) :

```
function manage_lists_cc_options_validate($input) {
    $options['text_string_0'] = $input[0];
    $options['text_string_1'] = $input[1];
    return $options;
}
```